A Borel set with convex sections has a Borel projection
The following is an exercise from "A Course on Borel Sets" by S.M. Srivastava.
Exercise 4.7.10 Let $X$ be a Polish space and $B \subseteq X \times \mathbb R^n$ a Borel set with convex sections (i.e. $B_x=\{y\in\mathbb R ^n: (x,y)\in B\}$ are convex). Show that $B_X$ is Borel.
I am in particular interested in whether such a proof would generalize to having $\mathcal P^1(\mathbb R ^n)$ instead of $\mathbb R^n$, where $\mathcal P^1(\mathbb R ^n)$ denotes the space of finite first order probability measures on $\mathbb R ^n$.
Any help would be very much appreciated!
Many thanks in advance!

I think the answr is in the affirmative and that it follows from the projection theorem ( see theorem here). The space you are interested is Polish with the Levy metric or the Prohorov metric)

Thanks for the comment! The linked theorem only gives me universal measurability, not Borel measurability :. The above result holds for sections that are either -singletons, -compact, -$\sigma$-compact  -open -nonmeager etc. Now I doubt that it holds for arbitrary Polish spaces (otherwise it would probably be a theorem in Srivastava), so I am hoping that the space of probability measures is similar enough to $\mathbb R ^n$ to make the proof valid there as well.

The only similarity is that under the Prohorov-Levy metric for example, $\mathcal{P}_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$  is a complete metric space. It is not separable however. Universal measurability is perhaps the best thing you may get.

What is $B_X$? In the second question, what exactly is being replaced? What is a “finite first order” probability measure and how can such be viewed as Borel?

@Michael $B_X$ is the projection of $B$ onto $X$. $\mathbb R ^n$ is being replaced by $\mathcal P ^1(\mathbb R^n)$. Finite first order means $\int |x| d\mu < \infty$. And being Borel can be defined in any topological space.
